# Are the goroutine numbers shown in a stack trace reused or incremented in golang?

Tags: go

Haven't found any information about what the goroutine "numbers" in a stack trace mean exactly. A Google search brings up some references about [interpreting stack traces](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2015/01/stack-traces-in-go.html) and [posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/txNixC7Rhug) that seem to indicate that numbers are resused, but no definitive question and answer asked that I can find.

Are the numbers shown in a Go stack trace reused or are they incremented? If I see a large number does that mean there are at least that many goroutines currently alive?

For example, consider the following stack trace:

```
goroutine 127590 [running]:
crypto/sha256.(*digest).checkSum(0xc042bb57d8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/sha256/sha256.go:247 +0x26d
```

Does this mean there are 127590 goroutines currently running?

Answer (score 3):

If the king is named Henry VIII, does this mean that Henrys I to VII are still alive? These are just numbers to distinguish one from another.

It is an id of goroutine. You cannot conclude that it is a number of alive goroutines. It is similar to the process id in the operating system. The ids are [cached](https://github.com/golang/go/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=goidcache&type=) and some may not be used.

To see how id of goroutine is generated search for [goidgen](https://github.com/golang/go/search?q=goidgen&unscoped_q=goidgen) in Go source code.

In Linux only process 0 is special in Go only goroutine 1 (main) is special.

See [Why is there no goroutine ID?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#no_goroutine_id)

> Goroutines do not have names; they are just anonymous workers. They expose no unique identifier, name, or data structure to the programmer. Some people are surprised by this, expecting the go statement to return some item that can be used to access and control the goroutine later.

Comment: I've got a package that surfaces a unique ID for goroutines started with the api in the package if you are interested:  github.com/jwells131313/goethe.  Also has some nice utilities around these threads like thread-local storage and the like

Comment: Based on the go code in [src/runtime/proc.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.18/src/runtime/proc.go#L4134), the "cache" actually acts as "batch allocator" for goroutine IDs ("goid"s), per "P" or "processor". Every P grabs a batch of 16 goids and then assigns them as it needs to create a new "G" goroutine. Thus, not all goids might be used, as this depends on the P and thus a batch of goids where a new G gets created. However, unless you manage to create 2**64 goroutines so that the scheduler's "master" goid counter wraps around, goids don't get reused.